# Update TreeView node from background thread by reference

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have a TreeView that has many nodes. I have a background worker that iterates through the nodes and either adds nodes, or updates the Checked property. Is it possible to update the node from my background thread if I pass the node to the background thread as a reference (I'm using the SyncronizationContext class to update controls that were created on the main thread)? Just curious if I can or not because it's ALOT of programming change if I can/can't do it from my background thread.

Comment: Investigate the [`Control.Invoke` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx), or [`Control.BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx).

Comment: This is yet another situation that suits a virtual control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update controls outside the UI thread. But you can invoke some function on the UI thread using `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke` (for WPF) or `Control.Invoke` (for WinForms). You should remember that those operations will be executed on the main thread and can make your application unresponsive if you try to do something time consuming here

Comment: I'm using the Synchronizationcontext class to update the main thread....don't remember where i found the article, but the code goes something like this:
    private readonly SynchronizationContext synContext = new AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext;

And to make the call, create a method that accepts arguments for the data that you need, then make the call like this (from the backgroundworker thread)
    syncContext.Post(delegate { OnUpdateUIControl(argsForUpdate); }, null);

Comment: Your code should work fine too (except for the fact you don't need the word "new" in your sample)